# python image (.jpeg) to hex code

Tags: python, printing, hex

I operate with a thermal printer, this printer is able to print images, but it needs to get the data in hex format. For this I would need to have a python function to read an image and return a value containing the image data in hex format.
I currently use this format to sent hex format to the printer:

```
content = b"\x1B\x4E"
```

Which is the simplest way to do so using Python2.7?
All the best;

Comment: Python Imaging Library (PIL) is the main image manipulation library although it has been abandoned for some years (3.x fork is Pillow). It is still the best fit for basic image operations. You can also use OpenCV to read images. You will still have to figure out how to alter the raw pixel data into the format needed by your printer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean by "hex format", but if it needs to get the whole file as a sequence of bytes you can do:

```
with open("image.jpeg", "rb") as fp:
    img = fp.read()
```

If your printer expects the image in some other format (like 8bit values for every pixel) then try using the [pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#) library, it has many image manipulation functions and handles a wide range of input and ouput formats.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
with open('something.jpeg', 'rb') as f:
    binValue = f.read(1)
    while len(binValue) != 0:
        hexVal = hex(ord(binValue))
        # Do something with the hex value
        binValue = f.read(1)
```

Or for a function, something like this:

```
import re
def imgToHex(file):
    string = ''
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        binValue = f.read(1)
        while len(binValue) != 0:
            hexVal = hex(ord(binValue))
            string += '\\' + hexVal
            binValue = f.read(1)
    string = re.sub('0x', 'x', string) # Replace '0x' with 'x' for your needs
    return string
```

Note: You do not necessarily need to do the `re.sub` portion if you use `struct.pack` to write the bits, but this will get it into the format that you need

Answer (score 0):

Read in a jpg and make a string of hex values. Then reverse the procedure. Take a string of hex and write it out as a jpg file...

```py
import binascii

with open('my_img.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

print(data[:10])

im_hex = binascii.hexlify(data)

# check out the hex...
print(im_hex[:10])

# reversing the procedure
im_hex = binascii.a2b_hex(im_hex)
print(im_hex[:10])

# write it back out to a jpg file
with open('my_hex.jpg', 'wb') as image_file:
    image_file.write(im_hex)
```